# Choose spreadsheet in google webapp

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs

I want to make a google script for generating a folderstructure for schoolclasses.
I want to load student names and emails by a spreadsheet. In the UI you should be able to choose which spreadsheet to use.

The folder structure isn't a problem but I'm having problems with choosing and loading the spreadsheet.

I want it to be a webapp, not a script in the spreadsheet app.

Should I use fileUpload and try to concert it from a blob? Any one with a clean solution?

Answer (score 2):

This should be fairly easy using basic Ui elements in a doGet structure.
I assumed that the spreadsheets you need to select are all in a folder called 'dataSpreadsheets' but you can of course customize that to your personal preferences.

Try this little code : ( [test app available here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzvmW88SFiDZzaha0bbc3s7h9bc-qU0YVc879e1KNJxSTdbw885/exec), asking for authorization since works on your account)

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication()
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel().setWidth('100%').setStyleAttributes({'padding':'50px','backGround':'#eeeeee'});
  var list = app.createListBox().setName('list');
  var handler = app.createServerHandler('getSS').addCallbackElement(panel);
  var btn = app.createButton('Select this spreadsheet', handler);
  var ssList = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('dataSpreadsheets');
  while (ssList.hasNext()){
    var folder = ssList.next();
  }
  if(folder!=null){
    var ss = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
    while (ss.hasNext()){
      var spreadSheet = ss.next();
      list.addItem(spreadSheet.getName(),spreadSheet.getId())
    }
  }else{
    app.add(panel.add(app.createHTML('No folder named "dataSpreadsheets" in your Drive')));
    return app;
  }
  app.add(panel.add(list).add(btn))
  return app;
}

function getSS(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(e.parameter.list);
  Logger.log(ss.getDataRange().getValues());
  // do what you have to do
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

No  reason to reinvent a file picker when gas has its own filepicker popup dialog. Use it. For uiapp see  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/docs-list-dialog